# Formatting itextsharp table

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I have a given table with 2 columns which I try to export to pdf.

This is my code:

```
PdfPTable tableUebersicht = new PdfPTable(dtUebersicht100.Columns.Count);
tableUebersicht.SetWidths(new float[] { 250, 420 });
tableUebersicht.LockedWidth = true;
tableUebersicht.TotalWidth = 500f;

foreach (DataColumn c in dtUebersicht100.Columns)
{
    PdfPCell Spalte = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, VerdanaFont));
    Spalte.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Spalte.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    table.AddCell(Spalte);
}
foreach (DataRow dr in dtUebersicht100.Rows)
{
    PdfPCell Spalte0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dr[0].ToString(), VerdanaFont));
    Spalte0.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Spalte0.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

    double Double1 = Convert.ToDouble(dr[1].ToString());
    PdfPCell Spalte1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string.Format("{0:C2}", Double1), VerdanaFont));
    Spalte1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    Spalte1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

    table.AddCell(Spalte0);
    table.AddCell(Spalte1);
}

table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 35, 757, cb);
```

The output looks as followed:
[image]

As you can see the table direction is from left to right and not from up to down.

I would like to have a table like this where the direction is up to down, on the bottom of the page get up and continue left beside, every second row colored:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

overview of the solution

- look at the table header, there are 4 columns
- generate an iText table object, with 4 columns
- add cells in the order left to right, top to bottom
  in your case that would be:
  Verkaufernummer, Betrag, Verkaufernummer, Betrag
  1, 55.04, 50, 3.5
- keep track of the row you are currently rendering on, depending on the row, set the background color of the cell (in your logic even vs odd)

Comment: Thanks, I created 4 columns for the table. How can I set that it only shows me the 4 columns and leave the right side blank? Currently is adds three more columns even if I say `PdfPTable tableUebersicht = new PdfPTable(4);`

Comment: in iText7, Table accepts a constructor that takes an absolute number of points as the sizes of the columns. By using this constructor, you can easily create a table that only spans the given width.